# Link to a file working only with file name without space

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a database of documents (thus several kind of files .pdf, .xlm, .ppt etc..)
I decide to store in mysql the path of the file, but when I build a link to them in order to download the selected file, it works only if the file name has no spaces, in case of space the link include only the first word:

```
 <?php
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Documents") or die(mysql_error()); 
 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 //Outputs the file data ad link to download the file:

 Echo "<b>Protocol:</b> ".$info['Protocol'] . "<br> "; 
 Echo "Here DOC_POINTER =".$info['doc_pointer']."<br>";
 Echo "<a href=http://localhost/VQ%20TESTs/DocUploaded/".$info['doc_pointer'].">Il           Documento Relativo</a><br>"; 
 Echo "<b>Name:</b> ".$info['doc_name'] . "<br> "; 
 Echo "<b>Type:</b> ".$info['doc_type'] . " <br>"; 
 Echo "<b>Manager:</b> ".$info['doc_manager'] . " <hr>"; 
 }
 ?>
```

if the file is called '123.pdf' everything works, the name is properly printed "Here Doc_pointer = 123.pdf" and the link goes to

http://mysite/VQ%20TESTs/DocUploaded/123.pdf>

While if the file is called 'Sales Chart.xlm' the print out is still file will be "Here Doc_pointer = Sales Chart.xlm" while the link will be only

http://mysite/VQ%20TESTs/DocUploaded/Sales>

and thus not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `str_replace` on `$info['doc_pointer']` and replace `' '` with `'%20'`

```
str_replace(' ','%20',$info['doc_pointer'])
```

Or just format your a href correctly:

```
Echo "<a href=\"http://localhost/VQ%20TESTs/DocUploaded/".$info['doc_pointer']."\">Il           Documento Relativo</a><br>";
```

by surrounding the address with " quotations "

Comment: url_encode was replacing spaces with + and not working yet, but I found in related documentation raw url_encode and it works.